# Problems with rosrun, rosws and others

Tags: ros, rosws, rosrun

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there. I use ROS Fuerte and I have a problem in a computer. When I use `rosrun`, `roscreate-pkg` and `rosws` some errors are happening. I'd like a help from you. For example, when I type: `$ rosws init ~/fuerte_workspace /opt/ros/fuerte` the console showed:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/rosws", line 52, in <module>
    import rosinstall.rosws_cli
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rosinstall/__init__.py", line 33, in <module>
    import rosinstall.helpers
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rosinstall/helpers.py", line 37, in <module>
    from rosinstall.config_elements import SetupConfigElement
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rosinstall/config_elements.py", line 38, in <module>
    from vcstools.vcs_abstraction import get_vcs_client
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/vcstools/__init__.py", line 43, in <module>
    from vcstools.svn import SvnClient
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/vcstools/svn.py", line 44, in <module>
    import dateutil.parser  # For parsing date strings
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dateutil/parser.py", line 24, in <module>
    from six import text_type, binary_type, integer_types
ImportError: No module named six
```

Can anyone help me? It is making a lot of problem for me.

Thanks so much!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/69949/problems-with-rosrun,-rosws-and-others/) by [MarcosPB](https://answers.ros.org/users/5429/marcospb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-07-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That specific error looks like you are missing the six module, but the last line of the traceback:

```
...
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dateutil/parser.py", line 24, in <module>
    from six import text_type, binary_type, integer_types
ImportError: No module named six
```

You can see that the `dateutil` module is coming from `/usr/local/lib/...` and everything else is coming from `/usr/lib/pymodules/...`. This looks like a problem with mixing `pip` and `apt-get`. See:

http://answers.ros.org/question/49143/problems-with-rqt-groovy-ubuntu/?answer=49153#post-id-49153

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2013-07-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1